# Angular check for a value in an array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs

I have `Likes` array which contains users who liked a post

```
Likes: [{username: "xyz" name: "xyz"}, {username: "pqr" name: "pqr"}]
```

In the view I want to check if a user already clicked like, so that I can show unlike the next time.

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-link">Like</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-link">UnLike</button>
```

Can someone tell me how to filter the `Likes` array for a username, so that I can use that with `ng-show`.

Comment: post code sample/what you already have...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 <button type="button" data-ng-hide="(likes | filter:{username: 'username'}).length >0">Like</button>
 <button type="button" data-ng-show="(likes | filter:{username: 'username'}).length >0">UnLike</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest that you use an associative array instead of the array of objects that you're currently using.

```
var likes = [];
likes['xyz'] = {liked: true};
likes['pqr'] = {liked: false};
```

That way you can write a function to check and flip the 'liked' flag, and a function to check the flag.

```
$scope.onClick = function(user) {
  if (!$scope.liked[user]) return;
  $scope.liked[user].liked = !$scope.liked[user].liked;
}

$scope.showLike = function(user)
{
  if (!$scope.liked[user]) return;
  return $scope.liked[user].liked;
}
```

and in your html:

```
<button ng-click="onClick('xyz')" ng-show="!showLike('xyz')">
  like
</button>

<button ng-click="onClick('xyz')" ng-show="showLike('xyz')">
  unlike
</button>
```

See this [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/AdamAxtmann/fx5g7sfv/2/)

Comment: Got a little ahead of myself there. You can simulate an associative array in javascript by taking advantage of weak typing though.

Comment: yeah..that's more like it. Also note need strings in interpolation markup